# I have created API Authentication using laravel passport.When authorization token get wrong its send me an error "Route [login] not defined"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have created API Authentication using laravel passport.When authorization token get wrong its send me an error "Route [login] not defined" although I need JSON response like "unauthorized 401"

**This is api.php** Here `users/authenticate` is a login route but when I use other routes which are inside the `auth:api` middleware. If token will be wrong its send me an error "Route [login] not defined" but I dont need this error. I need JSON error like {error:unauthorized , code:401}.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
    Route::post('users/authenticate', ['uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);






Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {    
    /* Business details for New register business, get all business, update business, get single business */
    Route::post('businesses/create', ['uses' => 'Business\BusinessController@businessRegister']);
    Route::post('businesses/{id}', ['uses' => 'Business\BusinessController@businessUpdate']);
    Route::get('businesses/{id}', ['uses' => 'Business\BusinessController@businessGet']);
    Route::get('businesses-info/{id}', ['uses' => 'Business\BusinessController@businessInfoGet']);

});
```

**this is auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

**This is AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
    }
}
```

**This is app.php**

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

**This is Handler.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }


}
```

Comment: I believe, when token not valid it is redirecting you to login route as per your `api.php` I'm not able to see any route with name `login`. but I'm not sure as I need more details to confirm.

Comment: whey do I need `login` route? Here I am using `api` I need `JSON` error return.

Comment: clear cache once php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: I did  php artisan optimize:clear . Still same `Route [login] not defined`

Comment: I am using laravel5.7

Comment: Can you paste code of you handler.php, `Path:` app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Comment: Ok check My code I have added `Handler.php`

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing same issue then I added `Auth::routes();` at the end of `web.php` then it started working.

I don't know if it is correct or not but it solved the issue.

Another reason can be that you are not sending laravel required headers i.e.

```
'accept' => 'application/json', //it tells server to send only json response
'content-type' => 'application/json'   // it tells front-end app to send data in json format
```

Hope it can solve your problem

Comment: ```'accept' => 'application/json', //it tells server to send only json response``` is correct

Answer (score 2):

You need to customize your code and add the following method in the code:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
           ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401)
           : redirect()->guest(route('users/authenticate'));
}
```

This will work for you

Comment: If proper headers are provided in request then laravel will automatically response in json. We don't have to add it ourself.

Comment: Fine but If I add Auth::routes(); at the end of web.php then ist work but even `Route [users/authenticate] not defined.`

Comment: Look my request `function getDashboard(data) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { ...authHeader(),'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    return fetch(apiUrl()+`/dashboard`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}`

Comment: Welcome, bro :) Keep Coding